# Finding the volume of Torus, Jacobian of spherical substitution.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

I thought to find the volume of a Torus, like I would a sphere, where the spherical substitution was: $$x=r\cos\varphi\sin \theta , y= r\sin\varphi \sin \theta, z=r\cos \theta \\ g(r,\varphi,\theta)\mapsto(x,y,z);J_g=r^2\sin\theta.\implies V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \int_{0}^{r}r^2dr$$
Can I do something similar with a torus? Like this?Since the large Radius is fixed?

$$x=(R+r\cos\theta)\cos \varphi , y=(R+r\cos\theta)\sin \varphi, z=r\sin \theta \\ g(r,\varphi,\theta)\mapsto(x,y,z);J_g=R+r\cos\theta\implies V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{r}(R+r\cos\theta) dr\ \ ??$$

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_spring_03/handouts/spheretorus.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral has serious problems (the bounds of integration don't define the torus in spherical coordinates), but the volume is well-known to be $(2\pi R)(\pi r^{2})$ by [Pappus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem). If you want to see this with integration, cylindrical coordinates (or the shell method from one-variable calculus) are easier than spherical.

(As written, incidentally, the volume integral for the sphere isn't quite OK, either: You're using $r$ to denote both the *radius function* and the *fixed radius of the sphere* whose volume you're calculating.)